# how can i get a frequency graph from the byte array of a wav file?

Tags: java, android, frequency-analysis

The purpose of the code below is turn a wav file into a byte array and graph the byte array. Does anyone know how to take the byte array from the wav file and turn that into an array that holds the frequency at each time?

```
buttonDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonDecode.setEnabled(false);
                buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

                GraphView thegraph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.thegraph);
                series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
                double x,y;
                x = 0;

                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(wavfile));

                    int read;
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
                    {
                        outt.write(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                    outt.flush();
                    byte[] audioBytes = outt.toByteArray();

                    //int[][] graphData = getUnscaledAmplitude(audioBytes, 1);

                    for(int i = 0; i < audioBytes.length;i++){


                        //System.out.println(audioBytes[i]);
                        byte curByte = audioBytes[i];
                        //int curByte = graphData[0][i];
                        y = (curByte);
                        series.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y), true, audioBytes.length);
                        x = x + 1;
                        //x = x + (1 / RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
                    }
                    thegraph.addSeries(series);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                buttonDecode.setEnabled(true);
                buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);

                //GRAPHING SECTION


            }
        });
```